# ruby on rails login facebook get information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authentication, omniauth

I use omniauth-facebook and get information about users with this function in user.rb

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    user = User.create(name: auth.extra.raw_info.first_name,
                       surname: auth.extra.raw_info.last_name,
                       provider: auth.provider,
                       uid: auth.uid,
                       email: auth.info.email,
                       password: Devise.friendly_token[0, 20],
                  #   City: auth.extra.raw_info.location.name,
                      state: auth.extra.raw_info.locale.gsub(/_/, '-'),

                       gender: auth.extra.raw_info.gender,
                       language: auth.extra.raw_info.language|| { },
                       bio: auth.extra.raw_info.bio|| { },
                       work: auth.extra.raw_info.work|| { } ,
                       education: auth.extra.raw_info.education|| { })
    end                   
  user
end
```

but `auth.extra.raw_info.education|| { }, work: auth.extra.raw_info.work|| { }` , returns me something like this:

```
  ---
  - !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  school: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  id: '115686675112108'
  name: istituto magistrale
  type: High School
  - !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  school: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  id: '134968379850136'
  name: laurea in pedagogia
  year: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
  id: '116957165019970'
  name: '1986'
  type: College
```

I do not know if it is an array or what, my field of education is a string, how do I access school, name, year  or type?

If I try `auth.extra.raw_info.education.name` it says impossible convert integer to string

Comment: make it hash with `to_hash` and then take whatever you need

Comment: how? auth.extra.raw_info.education.to_hash.shool.name  ???

Comment: looks like this is yaml format ! http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/loading_yaml_documents.htm  so data = YAML::load(string) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using omniauth correctly, the data should already be converted internally to a hash
(make sure `auth` is `env["omniauth.auth"]`)

To get the first school name, use:

`auth.extra.raw_info.education[0].school.name`